# Encode object as dict without embedded object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an object (objectname) that I am currently trying to get a dict representation of using objectname. _ _ dict _ _

The object has another object embedded in it and as a result I get a "Cannot encode object error" - which makes sense

I don't want this embedded object to appear in the encoded dict as it's not relevent to that output, but I do want to retain it in the object being encoded as it has use throughout the life-cycle of the object.

Is there a good way to do this without deleting the sub object first?

Comment: just printing the `_dict__` throws that error? When I make a class with an attribute set to another class, I can print this without issue. What code causes the error?

Comment: To clarify the request from @JacobIRR, without showing the code that is causing the error it will be challenging to provide any assistance.

Comment: If the issue is cyclic references (an `A` has an attribute of type `B`, which directly or indirectly includes the original `A` as an attribute, which causes the `repr` to recurse infinitely), you might want to look at [the `reprlib.recursive_repr` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr) for defining your types' `__repr__` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def encode(self):
        # this is called a dict comprehension
        return {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items()
                if k != 'thing'}

o = MyClass()
o.x = 1
o.y = 2
o.thing = object()

print(o.encode())  # {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Comment: That'll do the job thanks, posted this question at the end of a very long week and just couldn't see this as a solution, but then could hardly see my monitors by that point also :D